# Rails 6 - InvalidAuthenticityToken on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, ruby-on-rails-6

I've seen no answers on SO so far that don't answer this without suggesting to just disable it (which I don't want to do).

Locally, everything works, but deployed to producton on Heroku I'm getting `InvalidAuthenticityToken`.

From everything I can see, everything is set up properly.

- Fresh app on `Rails 6.0.3.1` (so it's not migrated where the setting may be disabled by default)
- `RAILS_MASTER_KEY` set in Heroku for session
- `session_store.rb` set to `Rails.application.config.session_store :cookie_store, key: '__app_session', expire_after: 1.year`
- `csrf_meta_tags` in my layout as well as `csp_meta_tag`
- ajax not used, this is a plain `form_with`. I can see the CSRF tag in dev tools so I know it's in the HTML

I considered it maybe is because of this in `ApplicationController`:

```
before_action :authenticate
```

however it seems that `prepend: true` is no longer set within the application controller...

I tried overriding it anyway by just adding it (even though it's not there by default and it still doesnt work if I add this above the `before_action` line)

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception, prepend: true
```

**Edit** I'll also say the fixed Sidekiq showing *forbidden* when trying to issue DELETE commands as well (kill job button)

Comment: Are you self hosting in production? using SSL?

Comment: Heroku, with Cloudflare... however you saying that made me realize I never changed Flexible SSL to Full. If SSL is a potential source of problems that could be it.

Comment: Try that, even add `config.force_ssl = true` in `config/environments/production.rb` file

Comment: amazing, that worked. Can you put that as the answer so I can mark it? You can put a few options if you want (flexible ssl, force_ssl, etc). Also I should add that this fixed sidekiq displaying 'forbidden'

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try adding `config.force_ssl = true` in your `config/environments/production.rb` and make sure your SSL is configured properly like you said switching to `Full` SSL instead of `Flexible`.

Comment: Can you please help how we can do this with an app hosted on AWS EC2? I am trying to remove the "Forbidden" error on Sidekiq, when trying to perform "Retry All"

Comment: @DheerajAvvari Did you add `config.force_ssl = true` to your `config/environments/production.rb` file? And are you sure you've configured SSL properly in EC2? Which server are your running - Apache/Nginx? What are you using for SSL - certbot or soemthing else?

Comment: I'm using Cloudflare DNS + Heroku hosted and I can confirm this worked for me (Rails 7 alpha 2 )